# Apache Spark Dataframe - Get length of each column

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Question**: In Apache Spark Dataframe, using `Python`, how can we get the data type and length of each column? I'm using latest version of python.

Using `pandas` dataframe, I do it as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\TestFolder\myFile1.csv', low_memory=False)

for col in df:
        print(col, '->', df[col].str.len().max())
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spark, you would need to aggregate. This returns a similar result to your Pandas version:

```
df.groupBy().agg(*[F.max(F.length(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show(vertical=True)
```

Full test:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b'], 'col2': ['x','ab']})

for col in df:
    print(col, '->', df[col].str.len().max())
# col1 -> 1
# col2 -> 2

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.groupBy().agg(*[F.max(F.length(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show(vertical=True)
# -RECORD 0---
#  col1 | 1   
#  col2 | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark also has a [describe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe.html) similar to `Pandas` , which you can use in this case

```
sparkDF.describe()
```

Comment: I have edited the post to make it focus on length of columns only. I thought I should let you know so you answer accordingly.